# Fragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, dagger-2, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use Android navigation component to navigate from one fragment to another.

When I call

```
 itemView.findNavController().navigate(direction)
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MyFragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:523)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2851)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:859)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:793)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:716)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:907)
    at MyViewHolder$bind$1.onClick(MyViewHolder.kt:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

I guess this is because `MyFragment` is a `DaggerFragment`, and `DaggerFragment` is a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

However I have Jetifier enabled in my `gradle.properties` :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Is not that supposed to convert my v4 Fragment into an androidx Fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DaggerFragment has been deprecated so I got rid of it.

I bumped my Dagger version to 2.23.2 :

```
// Dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.2"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.2"

// Dagger Android
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.23.2"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.23.2"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.2"
```

My fragment now inherits **androidx** Fragment instead of DaggerFragment. To keep injection working I use **AndroidSupportInjection** :

```
class MyFragment : Fragment()  {
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
    }
}
```